# WAS Liberty: WebApplicationException with entity gives error in jersey 2.17

Tags: java, websphere, jersey-2.0, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I am facing an issue while upgrading my REST API project from jersey 1.19 to 2.17 in order to use jax-rs 2.0 specs. [AppServer: WAS Liberty]

```
bldr = Response.status(statusCode.getStatusCode()).
       type(outputFormat.toString() + "; charset=UTF-8").
       entity(new ErrorDTO("error msg", "error code"));

Response result = bldr.build();

throw new WebApplicationException(result);
```

The above piece of code works well in jersey 1.19 by serializing the entity in the response object. After upgrading to jersey 2.17, the following exception is thrown:

```
[5/21/15 20:06:23:479 IST] 0000002a com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.wsspi.genericbnf.exception.MessageSentException: Message already sent com.ibm.wsspi.http.HttpOutputStream flushBuffers" at ffdc_15.05.21_20.06.23.0.log
[5/21/15 20:06:23:483 IST] 0000002a com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt                                  E SRVE8056E: An unexpected exception occurred closing the output stream.
java.io.IOException: Invalid state
    at com.ibm.wsspi.http.HttpOutputStream.flushBuffers(HttpOutputStream.java:464)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.http.HttpOutputStream.close(HttpOutputStream.java:531)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.response.WCOutputStream.close(WCOutputStream.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.closeResponseOutput(SRTServletResponse.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.closeResponseOutput(SRTServletResponse.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1275)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.commit(ResponseWriter.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:413)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:737)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:464)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
```

Interestingly, when the entity was removed from Response object the above exception didn't occur. Was wondering whether its a limitation with the latest version of jersey or is this a WAS Liberty issue?

**UPDATE 1**
Works when deployed on Apache Tomcat, continues to fail in WAS Liberty. I also tried disabling jaxrs-1.1 feature in server.xml.

**UPDATE 2**
Encountered the same issue when deployed on WebSphere Application Server (WAS) v8.5. Looks as if the issue is WebSphere specific.

Comment: Could you show your ErrorDTO entity?

Comment: ErrorDTO encapsulates the error message and code. In v1.19, ErrorDTO object gets serialized to corr. JSON/XML representation. The client reads this info and renders it appropriately in the UI.